# DC Inductor Design Using Powder Cores

Tags: dc-dc-converter, inductor

I have a question regarding the design of DC inductors with the book TRANSFORMER AND INDUCTOR DESIGN HANDBOOK. Chapter 9 describes the design of powder cores.  A so-called core geometry constant is defined with

\$ Kg = \dfrac{Energy}{\alpha \cdot Ke} \$

Ke is the electrical constant and is defined with

\$ Ke = 0.145 \cdot Po \cdot Bm^2 \times 10^{-4} \$

Po is the output power and B is the magnetic flux density.

My questions, in case there is somebody here who knows this book or this design process (Kg-Method): What kind of constant (Ke) is this exactly?  Where does 0.145 come from?
Thanks!

Comment: This is Colonel's (the author's first name is Colonel, he is/was not in the military) ingenious method for determining the power handling ability of a core in a more accurate way than the area product.  It's in some respects an empirically derived method, so I wouldn't expect a rigorous mathematical derivation for all the constants and formulas, but in practical application it works very well.

Comment: There are several questions here what is &alpha; and Bm (guessing max/peak flux density).   Also we need to know what units are used: Po (watts?), Bm(Gauss/Tesla?),  &alpha; (no idea).

Comment: @JohnD Okay, then I am relieved that this method works well in practice.

Comment: @WarrenHill alpha is CopperLoss/OutputPower, Bm in Tesla, Po in Watts. You're right, I should have given this information from the beginning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The electrical constant found by Colonel is something found by doing experiments. The value 0.145 you can thus only produce by performing those same experiments Noah.

Comment: Thank you, that answers my question! :)